# But for my father, I wouldn't have achieved anything. Is this correct?

Tags: conditionals

I was wondering if anyone could confirm if this sentence is correct? 
It somehow doesn't sound or feel correct but I saw it written today. Can anyone give me any insight if it is right or wrong?

'But for my father, I wouldn't have achieved anything.'

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The *but for* there means *without [the influence of]*. As in, *if my father hadn't been around,*... .

Comment: The phrase "There but for the grace of God go I" is often (though probably incorrectly) attributed to John Bradford. Arthur Conan Doyle seemed to believe it came from Richard Baxter: "Why does fate play such tricks with poor, helpless worms? I never hear of such a case as this that I do not think of Baxter's words, and say, 'There, but for the grace of God, goes Sherlock Holmes.'"

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly correct.

> **but for:** except for; were it not for:
>
> ***But for the excessive humidity***, it might have been a pleasant day.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/but--for?s=t)

You can also say, "Had it not been for my father, I wouldn't have achieved anything."