# Had it not been vs If it were not for

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, differences, conditionals, conditional-perfect

I've just seen the following sentence on a band's biography:

> **Had it not been for** a studio theft, the band might never have made that song.

Then I was wondering if I can change this sentence to:

> **If it were not for** a studio theft, the band might never have made that song.

Is the second sentence correct? Are they interchangeable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answered at [But for my father I wouldn't have achieved anything ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281572/but-for-my-father-i-wouldnt-have-achieved-anything-is-this-correct/281575#281575).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is correct, however, "If it hadn't been for a studio theft, the band might never have made that song." would be a better choice for, say, exam  purposes. 
If it had not been = Had it not been (this is called inversion)
If it were not for  = Were it not for
Search conditionals for more information.